# Zend passing data to other view

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've tried many solutions that had the same questions like mine. But didn't found a working solution.

I have a controller:

```
event.php
```

And two views:

```
event.phtml
eventList.phtml
```

I use eventList to get data via ajax call so I want to populate both views with a variable named "eventlist" for example.

Normally I use this code for sending a variable to the view:

```
$this->view->eventList = $events;
```

But this variable is only available in `event.phtml`.

How can I make this available for eventlist.phtml? (without adding a second controller)

**Edit:**
I get this error now

```
Call to undefined method Page_Event::render()
```

Function:

```
private $_event;

public function init(){
        $dbTable = new Custom_Model_DbTable_Events();
        //Get Events
        $this->_event = $dbTable->getEntries($this->webuser->businessId); 
        $this->index();

    }
public function indexAction(){
        $this->eventList = $this->_event;
        $this->render();
        $this->render('eventlist'); 
    }
```

If I use `$this->view->render('event.phtml')` and `eventlist.phtml` it won't pass the data

I'm using zend version **1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables to other views using `render()`

```
 public function fooAction()
    {
        // Renders my/foo.phtml
        $this->render();

        // Renders my/bar.phtml
        $this->render('bar');
    }
```

Copy and paste this in your controller and rename your controller from `event.php` to `EventController.php`

```
class EventController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  private $_event;

  public function init(){
        $dbTable = new Custom_Model_DbTable_Events();
        //Get Events
        $this->_event = $dbTable->getEntries($this->webuser->businessId); 
        $this->index();

    }
  public function indexAction(){
        // You're calling the index.phtml here.
        $this->eventList = $this->_event;
        $this->render('event');
        $this->render('eventlist'); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a error I'm getting now. I do work in a cms build on zend so it's possible I don't have all controller actions available.

Comment: @JochemQuery can you paste the whole controller for me please? If it is very huge just put the indexAction and init() in it.

Comment: added it @daan. This is just all, the controller is not yet bigger than this

Answer (score 1):

To specify that only written @Daan

In your action:

```
$this->view->eventList= $events;
$this->render('eventList'); // for call eventList.phtml
```

In you View use : `$this->eventList`

Comment: It seems that my 'custom' controller can't access render(). I'm getting the error I posted in my question. I also work in a custom cms so that makes it more difficult probably

Comment: try `$this->render('eventList');` without  `.phtml`

Comment: I tried that with and without it @doydoy44 but render stays undefined

Comment: @JochemQuery, Just a quick qestion to be sure: Wath is your Zend version? (1?, 2?) :)

Comment: Version 1, I will add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You could render it within the view itself (eventList.phtml), rather than within the controller, using the same line of code you used above:

```
$this->render('event[.phtml]');
```